# "at this scale" vs "on this scale"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

When *scale* is used figuratively, which preposition is right: *on* or *at*?

Example:

> On/at this inter-national scale, your bank is so small that it is virtually invisible. If large banks go bust, so will yours.

Comment: They're both fine, and I can't think of any context where one or the other preposition might be particularly preferred (or avoided). My gut feel is ***on*** is probably more likely overall - but that's just a personal opinion, not something worth "learning".

Comment: *International* is usually spelled without a hyphen. Further, I'd use ***at** this international **level***, but if you wanna keep *scale*, I'd use ***on** this international **scale***.

Answer (score 2):

In your example

> **On** this inter-national scale, your bank is so small that it is virtually invisible.

You would use "***on***" when comparing.

> **at** scale

has meaning when talking about size of processing.

Unless you are talking about a specific grouping of banks, you might use

> On **an** inter-national scale, your bank is so small that it is virtually invisible.

Comment: Thank you. To show the difference, could you give an example starting with "At this inter-national scale" where "at" would fit, i.e., where we would be talking about the size of processing?

Comment: On a scale of one to ten. On an international scale. At this scale [architecture]; at a scale of 1:10 [also architecture]. International does not take a dash. [sorry]